# connection fail for the jupyter notebook

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to connect to my project in jyputer notebook. However, it pop up connection failed.
So far I have reinstall the whole anaconda, but it doesn't work.
[image]

This is the application launch error I also received

[image]

Comment: Please describe in detail the steps you did to connect

Comment: @kmkurn. I just open my anaconda as usual and click open the jupyter notebook. I select the project that I do. When it open my project, it try to connect a few second and I received the above respond. I wasn't sure how to fix it.

Comment: How did you open your anaconda?

Comment: @kmkurn Double click my anaconda navigator icon. I also just try to reconnect my workbook and it shows the application launch error as well.

Comment: @kmkurn I add the application launch error in the question as well.